# Message in white box behind game graphics in Dolphin emulator (4.0, Stable)

Tags: emulation, nintendo-gamecube, zelda-wind-waker, dolphin-emulator

I recently bought *The Legend of Zelda: Wind Waker*. Before I got hit really hard with the flu, I took apart my GameCube / entertainment center in my bedroom to put something else precious in its place.

The problem is that this "stable" emulator is giving me a message behind the game graphics. It's irritating. Any assistance with this?

This is how it looks: if the text does not show up, the white boxes do.

[image: Screenshot of the menu 'File Selection': if the text does not show up, the white boxes do.]

Comment: I got it to somewhat disappear. If it's not the words, it's the backdrop for the message taking over bits of the emulation.

Comment: Does this issue still happen with Dolphin 5.0?